# Random image service

Tags: javascript, php, web-services

I need to show a random image (in some particular category or tag(s) ) on my webpage.

Is there such services that make me able to fetch random images from them by php or javascript?

I know some but their repository is very small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

> I need to show a random image (in some particular category or tag(s) ) on my webpage.

**Solution:**

You can use `setInterval()` and `random()` methods to achieve random image rotation in javascript. The `setInterval()` method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds), and `random()` method returns a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). Let me explain how this rotation thing works. (Tested)

Suppose you have four images, like this:

- firstimage.png
- secondimage.png
- thirdimage.png
- fourthimage.png

**HTML**

This is a simple image tag to display the image

```
<!--display an image initially-->
<img id="myImage" src="firstimage.png" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

First get the id of image tag

```
// Get the id of image tag
var myImage = document.getElementById("myImage");
```

Then store the path of all the images in an array, like this:

```
// store the path of all the images in an array
var imageArray = ["firstimage.png", "secondimage.png", "thirdimage.png", "fourthimage.png"];
```

Then write a function to rotate the image in equal interval of time, like this:

```
// function to rotate images after specified interval(3 seconds in this case)
function imageRotation(){
    // since we have four images hence we've taken 4 as a multiplier to get random number between 0 and 3
    var imageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4); 

    // set appropriate attribute
    myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
}
```

Note that the above `imageRotation()` function uses `random()` function to generate random number between 0 and 3, and it decides which image is going to be selected next.

Now call the `setInterval()` function with appropriate parameters, like this:

```
// imageRotation will be called in every 3 seconds
var everyInterval = setInterval(imageRotation, 3000);
```

**Sidenote:** The `setInterval()` method will continue calling the function until `clearInterval()` is called, or the window is closed. So to stop this at any point of time, we have `clearInterval()` function. For example, if you want a behaviour where, when the user hovers his/her mouse over an image, the rotation will stop, then you can do something like this:

```
// when the user hovers his/her mouse over an image, the rotation will stop
myImage.onhover = function(){
    clearInterval(everyInterval);
}
```

Here's the complete working code,

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

    <!--set an image initially-->
    <img id="myImage" src="firstimage.png" />

<script>
    window.onload = function(){

        // Get the id of image tag
        var myImage = document.getElementById("myImage");

        // store the path of all the images in an array
        var imageArray = ["firstimage.png", "secondimage.png", "thirdimage.png", "fourthimage.png"];

        // function to rotate images after specified interval(3 seconds in this case)
        function imageRotation(){
            // since we have four images hence we've taken 4 as a multiplier to get random number between 0 and 3
            var imageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4); 

            // set appropriate attribute
            myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
        }

        // imageRotation will be called in every 3 seconds
        var everyInterval = setInterval(imageRotation, 3000);

        // when the user hovers his/her mouse over an image, the rotation will stop
        myImage.onhover = function(){
            clearInterval(everyInterval);
        }

    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edited:**

**Problem:**

> Is there such services that make me able to fetch random images from them by php or javascript?

**Solution:**

To get large repository of images you can either use [TinEye API](https://services.tineye.com/TinEyeAPI), [flickr API](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/) or [BOSS Search API](https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/). Google's API is officially deprecated as of November 1, 2010.

Comment: Thanks but i know how to add image element in html; I need a imaging service with a large repository of images that make me able to load images from there

Comment: Yes, you can do that. All you need to do is to store paths of all the images in `imageArray`.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. I've edited and reformatted my answer. I didn't see the second part of the question. So this answers the first part of the question, *I need to show a random image (in some particular category or tag(s) ) on my webpage*. And for the second part, see the **edited** section of my answer. Hope this will help you.